# Convert CudnnGRU params to normal weights and bias

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am using the `CudnnGRU` class from `tensorflow.contrib.cudnn_rnn`, the training speed is much faster. However after training I need to move the model to an system which is not CUDA based. So how can I convert the `CudnnGRU` params to normal weights and bias, then load them into `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnCompatibleGRUCell`?

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow 2 version for both `CuDNNGRU` and normal `Tensorflow` based `GRU` has been brought to a same layer which is [tf.keras.layers.GRU](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU).
Based on the available runtime hardware and constraints the layer will choose either `cuDNN` or `TensorFlow` based implementations.
If a GPU is available and all the arguments to the layer meet the requirement of the `CuDNN` kernel (see below for details), the layer will use a fast `cuDNN` implementation.

The requirements to use the `cuDNN` implementation are:

1. activation == tanh
2. recurrent_activation == sigmoid
3. recurrent_dropout == 0
4. unroll is False
5. use_bias is True
6. reset_after is True
7. Inputs, if use masking, are strictly right-padded.
8. Eager execution is enabled in the outermost context.